# C++: warning: '...' declared with greater visibility than the type of its field '...::<anonymous>'

Tags: c++, gcc, visibility, warnings, gcc-warning

I'm getting these two warnings (with GCC 4.2 on MacOSX):

/Users/az/Programmierung/openlierox/build/Xcode/../../src/main.cpp:154:0 /Users/az/Programmierung/openlierox/build/Xcode/../../src/main.cpp:154: warning: 'startMainLockDetector()::MainLockDetector' declared with greater visibility than the type of its field 'startMainLockDetector()::MainLockDetector::<anonymous>'

/Users/az/Programmierung/openlierox/build/Xcode/../../src/main.cpp:154:0 /Users/az/Programmierung/openlierox/build/Xcode/../../src/main.cpp:154: warning: 'startMainLockDetector()::MainLockDetector' declared with greater visibility than its base 'Action'

In this code:

```
struct Action {
    virtual ~Action() {}
    virtual int handle() = 0;
};


static void startMainLockDetector() {
    /* ... */

    struct MainLockDetector : Action {
         bool wait(Uint32 time) { /* ... */ }
         int handle() { /* ... */ }
    };

    /* ... */
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what these warnings mean (what visibility?) and how to fix them. (I really want the class MainLockDetector to be local for that function only.)

I have already compiled the same code with a lot of other compilers (clang, GCC 3.*, GCC 4.0, GCC 4.4, etc) and never got any warning for this code.

Comment: What field `<anonymous>` does it mean? Please post the contents of the local class.

Comment: Ok, that is the full struct (without code).

Answer (score 6):

To fix this problem, try one of below.

1. Use `#pragma GCC visibility push()` statement like this.

   ```
   #pragma GCC visibility push(hidden)
   struct MainLockDetector : Action {
        bool wait(Uint32 time) { /* ... */ }
        int handle() { /* ... */ }
   };
   #pragma GCC visibility pop
   ```
2. Use `__attribute__ ((visibility("hidden")))` like this.

   ```
   struct __attribute__ ((visibility("hidden"))) MainLockDetector : Action {
        bool wait(Uint32 time) { /* ... */ }
        int handle() { /* ... */ }
   };
   ```
3. Add the command line option -fvisibility=default.

For more details, refer http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility.

Comment: In my case I needed `struct __attribute__ ((visibility("hidden"))) StructName{....};`

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a problem with shared libraries. I assume you are writing a shared library. Look at [this explanation](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf). Try to add the command line option `-fvisibility-inlines-hidden`. The problem seems to be, that gcc tries to export some symbols of `MainLockDetector` (visible to linking executables and libraries), whereas `Action` is not exported (invisible to linking executables and libraries). So the visibility of `MainLockDetector` really is higher than the visibility of `Action`.

Comment: No, it's not a shared library, it's just an application. But why exactly is MainLockDetector exported and Action is not?

Comment: Have you read the linked paper. The interesting part is inside section 2.2.4.

Comment: Ok, have read it now (not all but 2.2.4 and a bit more, most of 2.*). Really interesting. But is `-fvisibility-inlines-hidden` related to my problem? Because I have startMainLockDetector not stated as inline explicitely. Also, why exactly doesn't it export Action? As far as I understand the paper, everything should be exported by default, so why not Action?

Comment: I am a bit confused about the visibility stuff. I have formulated a seperate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843796/gcc-visibility-of-symbols-in-standalone-c-applications). Maybe this will also clarify things here.

Comment: Could you also tell us, if the change of the visibility attributes helped at all?

Comment: Yes, `-fvisibility-inlines-hidden` doesn't change anything. I just found out that my build environment also sets `-fvisibility=hidden`. So why does that not apply to `MainLockDetector`?

Comment: If `-fvisibility-inlines-hidden` didn't help at all and the other changes in visibility (attributes of pragmas) do not work too, maybe the problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score -6):

It's because you forgot to declare the inheritance as public.

```
    struct MainLockDetector : public Action {
         bool wait(Uint32 time) { /* ... */ }
         int handle() { /* ... */ }
    };
```

This causes the "Action" members to be private. But, you've just overridden an Action private member as public (public default in a struct), which could break encapsulation, hence the warning.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. As you say yourself "public default in a struct", so the "public" is optional (it's the default for both members and inheritance).

Comment: No change, still same warning. Also 'public' doesn't make sense for structs.

Comment: Declaring the inheritance `public` doesn't have any bearing on this problem.